# MF522-an RFID reader - checking for the complete card number

Tags: locking, arduino, rfid

The code I am using is from *[How to get started with the Mifare MF522-AN and Arduino](http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/blog/2012/04/how-to-get-started-with-the-mifare-mf522-an-and-arduino/)*.

The problem is, that the code only checks for the first pair of the card number:

```
if(serNum[0] == 88) { // Is the first pair equal to 88?
    Serial.println("Hello Grant");
}
```

How do I get it to check for the complete card number?

Comment: I figured it out:) Use this code to get your card number in numbers not binary: Serial.println("The card's number is  : ");
   Serial.print(serNum[0]);
                        Serial.print(" , ");
   Serial.print(serNum[1]);
                        Serial.print(" , ");
   Serial.print(serNum[2]);
                        Serial.print(" , ");
   Serial.print(serNum[3]);
                        Serial.print(" , ");
   Serial.print(serNum[4]);
                        Serial.println(" ");

Comment: It is perfectly all right to post an answer to your own question. See e.g. *[Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)*. There is even for a badge for it, *[Self-Learner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)*.

Answer (score 1):

hope this code will help you out:

```
                    String FullSerial = "";
                    FullSerial += serNum[0];
                    FullSerial += serNum[1];
                    FullSerial += serNum[2];
                    FullSerial += serNum[3];
                    FullSerial += serNum[4];

                    if(FullSerial == "THE_RFID") { //Change the Condition
                      Serial.println("Hello Grant");
                    }
```